# Mysql Out of memory (Needed 536870945 bytes)

Tags: mysql, rds

I'm trying to import an sql file into aws RDS database the file size is 1.5 GB
i'm connecting to the rds from ec2 instance then executing this command

> "source sqldata.sql"

to import it into the rds then im getting this error

> mysql: Out of memory (Needed 536870945 bytes)

Do i need to increase some values if so what they are?

> RDS is
>   4 GB RAM
>   2  CPU Cores

Answer (score 1):

Check your reference manual for upper limit of max_allowed_packet, please.  File size may be limited to this max, as well.

Comment: i tried splitting the 1.5GB file into smaller ones 250MB and it worked, so the problem is with the file size not the query itself ,i will test your suggestion

Comment: the max_allowed_packet is 953MB it must be another variable , any ideas

Comment: Please post last 400 lines of your error log, it may have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was years ago but I received the exact same error message using aws rds aurora serverless v2 which had more than enough memory. I made many changes to the rds but in the end I just increased the memory of the ec2 instance that was running the restore query from a 1gb mem to a 8gb memory instance and that worked. So always check the ec2 instance, the error message mislead me to think it was the rds at fault.